# Cannot recover from Windows Server Backup after expanded volume

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, backup-restoration, windows-server-backup, diskpart, vhdx

I am running a Windows Server 2012 r2 instance on Hyper-v, I set up Windows Server Backup to run every night to incrementally back up a large folder. The folder sits on the same Virtual Hard Disc as the virtual server (Disk 0 : Volume C:) but the backup location is on another Virtual Hard Disc mounted to the same virtual server (Disk 1 : Volume E:).

Today I tried to recover an older version of this folder to a folder in (Disk 0 : Volume F:) and it failed because volume F: ran out of space. So I shut down the server, expanded the Disc 0 VHDX, started the server and extended Volume F: in Disk Management. Note that I did not change anything in the Disk 1 VHDX.

Now if I try to run the recovery for any date other than yesterday, I get the following error:
[Unable to browse Local disk (C:). Windows Backup cannot find a shadow copy of the backup set on the storage location.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYnQK.png)

Is there any way for me to still recover older versions of this folder?